Default route fallback by looking at pings
I'm having a Ubuntu server connected with single interface to multiple routers. These routers are not co-located, so a single router with bunch of fallback WANs does not work AFAIK.
I can set default route individually for all of them, but only the with highest metric is used. They are not reliable uplinks (namely Starlinks and mobile networks), so I would prefer to have them dynamically adjust metrics (or add/delete routes) based on pings via these specific gateways.
I do have a rough understanding of which one should work the best, so I think it's ok to add/delete routes based on predetermined preference order.
My (limited) understanding of bonding with fallback tells me that it will not work here, since because the interface is still up, even if one uplink comes down.
Right now, my plan is to build a custom python app that will continuously ping via all gateways and adjust routes accordingly based on connection.
However, I just wanted to check if anyone is aware of solutions/programs that would work out of the box in this case?
